# When are UI elements created on Android?

Tags: android, view

At which point are Android views created?  When the activity starts?  When the app is started?  When a call to setContentView() is made?  Or at some other point?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Your question is quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean when is it safe to get the objects of your view?

If you refer to Activities, in the `onCreate` method, after you call `setContentView(...)` you can start calling `findViewById(...)` to refer to the objects of your view.

In the case of Fragments, the view is created in the `onCreateView(...)` method. You can refer to the view in the `onActivityCreated(...)` callback, this is called after the Activity has been created, so it is safe to refer to the view here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the UI is created when the activity is called because the first activity is calling when the program is starts. In the onCreate method, you can define your views, so it will be created when the activity is created.