# Can we get a view height in onCreate()

Tags: android, view, widget

Can we get a view height in onCreate().here i am trying to find the height of a view using view.getHeight() but it is showing 0 in debuger

Comment: in an activity or fragment ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718036/when-are-ui-elements-created-on-android?rq=1

Comment: Use `ViewTreeObserver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions. Your views are *instantiated* as soon as your layout is inflated. This means that immediately after the call to `setContentView()` you can retrieve them using `findViewById()` and call methods on them (such as `setText()` etc).

However, while the views *exist* at this point, they have not yet been laid out. Only after the views go through a layout pass will they have real values for position and dimensions.

As Ayush's answer says, you can be notified when the layout pass is complete by registering a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` for the view you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the height of View class when it has been created. In other words you have to calculate it in the View#post() method.

```
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Find height here
            // e.g
            // view.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

Comment: still i am getting height 0 inside the onGlogalLayout()

Comment: When did I said to get height in onGlobalLayout()? Use post method of the view class

Answer (score 0):

A ViewTreeObserver gets fired for different drawing events. Usually the OnGlobalLayoutListener is what you want for getting the measurement

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            view.getHeight(); //height is ready
        }
    });
```